# Retrieve the home page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I worked on [this](http://toolskaart.com/). But our client accidentally did something which led to home page not displaying. Upon doing some research, I found that homepage is gone. I tried to look for the homepage file, but countn't get. I found some extension called trashcan like paid extension to retreive the file, but I cannot offer that. Please suggest me some free extension or some ideas from where I can get the home screen back.

Comment: please check that cms page and check that home page is enabled or disabled

Comment: The home page itself is not there. The client deleted that one.

Comment: Check CMS -> Pages find the home page. Check "Enabled" Property of the page.

Comment: I made a backup of the project. Are there any possibility that I get the file in that backup.

Comment: Check in  database table "cms_page" are you able to locate home page ? If not set things that are not present by tracking your backup.

Comment: tracking backup. How to do that. Please guide me.

Comment: did you possible change the key/code for the CMS homepage from 'homepage'. If you did that and never updated the config to use your page it could vanish.

Comment: if the home page is not present in CMS -> Pages Menu and in 'cms_page' database , Then you need to create a new page with URL key "home" copying content from your backup. I guess you have taken backup of both database and file structure right ?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your homepage content is located in a file. It is actually supposed to be located in your database and you can edit/create it in your admin panel: go to CMS > Pages, you can here create a new page. Now, to define this page as the homepage content, go to System Config > Web, here you can find the dropdown that specifies the CMS page matching the homepage. Just select the page you have just created, and make it the default page for homepage.